# Changing table name from lower case to upper case

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database that has 200 + tables.

Now, I have to import those table dumps to new database.

All the table name are in **small case letters**.

Is there any method, so I can convert all the table name with **small case letters** to **upper case letters** ?

Comment: You could write a short procedure to do this...

Answer (score 0):

In windows,Edit the my.cnf file

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

then
restart your server.